# What am I meant to do with Elder Scroll (Dragon) after completing Dawnguard?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

After completing the Dawnguard storyline in favor of the vampire hunters, I was able to give the 2 scrolls (sun and blood) to Dexion, however the dragon scroll remains in my inventory. Is there some special use for it? i've checked with Urag gro-Shub and he will not take it. Note that this is after I've completed the main questline.

Comment: Is it still a quest item? If it is, at least you won't have to worry about its weight.

Comment: @RavenDreamer yes, it is still a quest item. I guess Beth forgot to re-enable the option to sell it to Urag, maybe somebody who hasn't sold it before using it for Dawnguard can confirm.

Comment: You probably bought it back from Urag.There is a glitch where if you buy it back, he will not re-take it back like he should be doing. Just wait for a patch to fix the issue is your only option now. Or if you are on PC, trying to remove it via console command might work but could also screw up your save at the same time.

Comment: Any interesting side note - if you tried to read the Sun or Dragon scrolls during the mission they open, glow then your screen goes black and nothing more is shown from them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a bug in the game where if you buy back the [Elder Scroll (Dragon)](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Elder_Scroll#Elder_Scroll_.28Dragon.29) from [Urag gro-Shub](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Urag_gro-Shub) after earlier selling it to him, you won't be able to sell it to him again after completing the final Dawnguard DLC main quest, [Kindred Judgment](https://en.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Kindred_Judgment).

The bug is fixed by the **Unofficial Skyrim Patch**. Download links: [Original / Legendary Edition - PC](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/71214) / [Special Edition - PC](https://www.nexusmods.com/skyrimspecialedition/mods/266) / [PS4](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/4073181) / [Xbox One](https://bethesda.net/en/mods/skyrim/mod-detail/2947804).

Related [patch note](https://www.afkmods.com/Unofficial%20Skyrim%20Legendary%20Edition%20Patch%20Version%20History.html):

> UDGP v1.2.3 - (2013-06-29)
>
> After completing Kindred Judgment, it is not possible to sell the Dragon Elder Scroll back to Urag. This has been corrected. ([Bug #12490](https://afktrack.afkmods.com/index.php?a=issues&i=12490))

Comment: It is important to note that this will only work on pc

Comment: @3ventic I agree. Answer edited.

Answer (score 1):

The Dragon Elder Scroll is used as part of the main quest.  Paarthunax will tell you to go retrieve it if you haven't done the dawnguard quest that makes you get it.  I imagine it won't let you sell it so that you will have it on hand when you get to that point in the main quest.
(Note: By "the main quest" I mean fighting Alduin)

Comment: I've already completed it before starting Dawnguard.

Answer (score 1):

Get arrested and escape then grab everything but the scrolls.

Comment: Have you tried this? Quest items normally don't get removed from your inventory when you're put in jail.

Answer (score 0):

If you chose the Dawnguard side of the quest.Dexion Evicus will take all three elder scrolls off your hands for 6000 gold and take them to the imperial city, i'm not sure what to do if you chose the vampires side though.

Comment: Pretty sure he only takes the 2 scrolls introduced by Dawnguard.

Comment: He took all three when I did it

Comment: [I very much doubt that](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Moth_Priest).