# Urag gro-Shub won't buy the Elder Scroll

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, skyrim-dawnguard

I tried to sell the Elder Scroll to Urag gro-Shub and was unsuccessful. Now I have been trying to get rid of these damn things for a while. They are way too heavy. Do I have to fight the dragon before I can get rid of them?

Comment: Which Elder Scroll are you trying to sell to Urag gro-Shub? Is it Dragon, Sun, Blood or all of them? If it's Dragon, and you finished the Dawnguard DLC main questline, see: [What am I meant to do with Elder Scroll (Dragon) after completing Dawnguard?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/80339/4797)

Answer (score 3):

The Elder Scrolls are Quest items, therefor can't be sold until ALL related quests are completed.
So you got to check if the following quests are done:

- [Elder Knowledge](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Elder_Knowledge)
- [Alduin's Bane](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Alduin%27s_Bane)
- [Discerning the Transmundane](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Discerning_the_Transmundane)

And if Dawnguard is installed:

- [Scroll Scouting](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Scroll_Scouting)
- [Unseen Visions](https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Unseen_Visions)

Also because it is a quest item it won't weigh anything:
[Do quest items weigh anything?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/43291/do-quest-items-weigh-anything) as stated you can try it out by placing everything you own in a chest and check your weight.

Comment: The item will have a weight value but it does not actually count against the capacity.